# Unity - how to get set a variable at the first frame of movement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok, Im trying to create drag to resize functionality on a cube gameobject that has been flattened into a sort of plane. To do this, Ive placed the plane as the child of a container that ensures that scaling occurs from the upper left corner. The handle is a plane gameobject:

[image]

I believe I need to add the delta of the handle movement to the transform.parent.localScale of the PlaybookPanel. This requires that the initial position of the handle be stored and used to calculate the delta **each time a new drag begins.**

I dont know how to do this. So far I have:

```
bool isDragging = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        scaleHandle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ScaleHandle");
        scaleHandleInitialPos = scaleHandle.transform.localPosition;
        panelScaleInitial = transform.parent.localScale;

        width = 1f;
        height = 1f;
        thickness = 0.5f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        width = panelScaleInitial.x - (scaleHandleInitialPos.x - scaleHandle.transform.localPosition.x);
        height = panelScaleInitial.y + (scaleHandleInitialPos.y - scaleHandle.transform.localPosition.y);

        if(scaleHandle.transform.localPosition == scaleHandleInitialPos && !isDragging)
        {
            print("handle just started being dragged");
            isDragging = true;
        } else if (scaleHandle.transform.localPosition == scaleHandleInitialPos)
        {
            isDragging = false;
        }
        scaleHandleInitialPos = scaleHandle.transform.localPosition;

        transform.parent.localScale = new Vector3(width, height, thickness);

    }
```

But this does not work and results in a lot of jagged panel movement.

How can I correctly get the handle delta in order to drag to scale the panel on the x and y axis?

Comment: Id use a different approach, first check if button is down, is the pointer in the drag box, get the drag with delta (it's part of the event system or you can calculate it) apply it to the scale.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you store the localScale and position, try just using Scale. that should take in the global scale and fix the problem

Comment: What do you mean by that? I need localscale to scale the plane and position of handle to control that scale.

Comment: yes but for the initial position you should just use just Position. maybe create a new variable